# mysql foreign key, wont create mysql error message is Vague

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, key

```
ALTER TABLE cfg_scripts 
ADD CONSTRAINT cfg_scripts_priority_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (priority) 
REFERENCES cfg_script_priorities(script_priority);
```

Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint.
mysql fails it tell me actually why it cant

```
select priority 
from  cfg_scripts
where coalesce(priority,-1) not in  (select script_priority from cfg_script_priorities)
```

The above query returns no rows, so no key violations.

data types the same, can't see problem

would help if mysql error message could actually tell you the problem... i find mysql's error messaging terrible....

Comment: is ok forgot to create a primary key on table.... mysql error messaging is so useless... tells you nothing

Comment: You should delete your question or provide an answer and accept it.

Comment: i did above, i also filled in the answer question bit, stack exchange didnt display it?